# Swig: How to return a list of pointers from C++ to Tcl

Tags: c++, pointers, tcl, swig, stdvector

I want to return a list of pointers from C++ to Tcl. And then call some member functions by the pointers. SWIG can help me to do that.

However, SWIG give me a list of **pointer to pointer**.

```
% getLongTime 10
_30a8620000000000_p_p_MyData _30bc620000000000_p_p_MyData
```

I can't find the syntax to dereference in SWIG. So I have to write dereference functions for every class. It is very inconvenience.

I include "std_vector.i" to return the list of pointer. Anyone has an example that using vector but without second pointer? Or any alternative solution is OK!

I also have tried to write a general dereference function, like:

```
void * dereference(void ** p){ return *p; }
```

However, it doesn't work. Tcl gives me type error:

```
TypeError in method 'dereference', argument 1 of type 'void **
```

I simplified my code if you want to try my program. Here is my main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#include "main.hh"
#include <tcl.h>

std::vector<MyData> MyData::AllTime;            // It seems the place of this statement matters

std::vector<MyData*> getLongTime(int limit) {
    vector<MyData*> longTime;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
        if (MyData::AllTime[i].getMinute() >= limit )
            longTime.push_back(&MyData::AllTime[i]);
    return longTime;
}

MyData* derefMyData(MyData** p) {return *p;}    // I have to write a dereference function for every class

/// print command, exectue it and print resulte
void print(Tcl_Interp *interp, const char *command) {
    printf("%% %s\n", command);
    Tcl_Eval(interp, command);
    const char *msg = Tcl_GetStringResult(interp);
    if (*msg != '\0')
        printf("%s\n", msg);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
    Tcl_Eval(interp, "load ./swig.so swig");
    MyData::AllTime.push_back(MyData(10));
    MyData::AllTime.push_back(MyData(15));
    MyData::AllTime.push_back(MyData(9));

    // set the time exceeding 10 to 10 by tcl function.
    print(interp, "set times [getLongTime 10]");
    print(interp, "foreach t $times { [derefMyData $t] setMinute 10}");

    printf("All times:");
    for(std::vector<MyData>::iterator i = MyData::AllTime.begin(); i != MyData::AllTime.end(); ++i)
        printf("%d ", i->getMinute());
    printf("\n");

    Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my main.hh

```
#ifndef MAIN_HH
#define MAIN_HH

#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MyData{
    int minute;
public:
    MyData(int minute):minute(minute){};
    int getMinute(){return minute;};
    void setMinute(int m){ minute = m; };
    static std::vector<MyData> AllTime;
};

std::vector<MyData*> getLongTime(int limit);
MyData* derefMyData(MyData** p);
#endif /* MAIN_HH */
```

Here is my swig.i

```
/* swig.i */
 %module swig
 %{
#include "main.hh"
 %}
%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std {
    %template(myDataVector) std::vector<MyData *>;
}

class MyData{
public:
    MyData(int minute);
    void setMinute(int m);
};

extern std::vector<MyData*> getLongTime(int limit);
extern MyData* derefMyData(MyData** p);
```

Here is my compile commands

```
swig -c++ -tcl swig.i
g++ -fpic -c main.cpp swig_wrap.cxx 
g++ -shared main.o swig_wrap.o -o swig.so ;# I don't need to compile with main.o in my original program.
g++ main.o -o swig.out -g -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -ltcl8.5
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib
./swig.out
```

And here is the output:

```
% set times [getLongTime 10]
_30a8620000000000_p_p_MyData _80bb620000000000_p_p_MyData
% foreach t $times { [derefMyData $t] setMinute 10}
All times:10 10 9
```

By the way, the simplified program report *** glibc detected ***
I don't know how to fix it.
Fortunately, my original program is fine.
If anyone know how to fix it. Please let me know.

My SWIG version: 1.3.29
My gcc version: 4.5.2

Comment: Properly speaking, you should call `Tcl_FindExecutable(argv[0]);` from `main` before doing the `Tcl_CreateInterp`, as that initialises the Tcl library, though I don't think that'll fix things for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you've not got a SWIG typemap for `MyData *` but rather just for `MyData` (or perhaps `&MyData`; my C++ is a little shaky). That's making SWIG generate code that isn't doing what you expect; the `_30a8620000000000_p_p_MyData` is a handle to the cell in the value copied from the `longTime` local variable, and so that handle's mapped type is pointer to cell contents, i.e., `MyData **`.

You *might* get better results if you return a `const vector<MyData *>`. That would certainly make more sense on the Tcl side, where values themselves are actually constant. I don't know whether SWIG is smart enough to take advantage of that though. It's possible you'll have to write the typemap code yourself (which is only sensible if your real code is a lot longer than this).